# Is there a way to find/replace in a selected text in TeXstudio

Tags: texstudio

I'd like to know if there is a way to do find/replace in a selected text in TeXstudio.

Comment: Have you asked the support of TeXStudio? Can you explain your issue better, for example with an screenshot ...

Comment: In scientific word, it allows you to find/replace in a selection of text, a function that I believe is important. So I wonder if there is such a function in texstudio.

Comment: On Windows you can activate find/replace in TXS with `ctrl-r`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes there is a way: start find/replace (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> or `Edit > Searching > Replace`) and select the button with text "Select" (see image below).

[image]